# Why does cookielib.LWPCookieJar accept an empty argument list?

Tags: python, cookies

In the cookielib documentation, the definition of [cookielib.LWPCookieJar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#file-cookie-jar-classes) is:

```
class cookielib.LWPCookieJar(filename, delayload=None, policy=None)
```

The filename is a required argument.

But in the following python code, `LWPCookieJar` has no argument, yet still works.

```
import cookielib
cookie = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
```

Who knows why?

Comment: Because you aren't calling the constructor? You're just referencing the class `LWPCookieJar`. `LWPCookieJar` != `LWPCookieJar()`

Comment: @Rawing I am sorry. I mean LWPCookieJar() not LWPCookieJar. I have corrected the problem desciption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the documentation is lying, apparently.

`cookielib.py` imports the definition of [`LWPCookieJar`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/_LWPCookieJar.py#l49) from `_LWPCookieJar.py`, which defines it as:

```
class LWPCookieJar(FileCookieJar):
    ...
```

[`FileCookieJar`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/cookielib.py#l1749) is defined in `cookielib.py`, as:

```
class FileCookieJar(CookieJar):
    """CookieJar that can be loaded from and saved to a file."""

    def __init__(self, filename=None, delayload=False, policy=None):
    ...
```

So the `filename` argument is actually optional (and `delayload` defaults to `False`, not `None`).